# How do I draw a plot using pyqtgraph on PyQt4 widget created in QT Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I'm just starting with pyqtgraph. I have a graphicsView widget that I promoted with QT designer per the documentation. I would like to try a plot to see if it works. When I tried `pg.plot(x,y)` the program created a plot in a separate window rather than in the graphicsView widget. I'm using Windows 10, PyQt4, and Python 2.7. What am I doing wrong?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import ui_test  #Gui File
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg


class Gui(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui_test.Ui_MainWindow):


    def __init__(self):        
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()        
        self.setupUi(self)  # This is defined in ui_pumptest.py file automatically   
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):       
        vb = pg.ViewBox()
        self.graphicsView.setCentralItem(vb)
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  # A new instance of QApplication
    form = Gui()  # We set the form to be our ExampleApp (design)
    form.show()  # Show the form
    app.exec_()  # and execute the. app

if __name__ == '__main__':  # if we're running file directly and not importing it
    main()  # run the main function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the ui_pumptest.py file source? Otherwise it's hard to tell what your intentions are.  If not, at least detail what construct you used to place in the QGraphicsView promotion process in QtDesigner (assuming you followed http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/how_to_use.html#embedding-widgets-inside-pyqt-applications).

pg.plot creates it's own plotwindow->plotwidget structure, so that's why you're getting a separate window if calling that.  The item you call plot on should be the container object name that was promoted in your Qt Ui file.